# Tachyon reactor

Tags: science-based, technology

My ship have a reactor core that accelerates tachyons within it, which lose energy as their velocity increases, generating energy.How my reactor core accelerates the tachyons and harness this energy ?

Comment: Given that tachyons are entirely theoretical, you can generate and accelerate them any way you like.

Comment: Or to rephrase: given that this is effectively magic and you can decide how this stuff works all by yourself, what is it that you expect to get from answers to your questions? Defining a magic system for you is a bit out of the scope of a simple Q&A.

Comment: @StarfishPrime: Saying that tachyons are *theoretical* debases the word theory. Tachyons are a wild speculation at best, and more usually they are just a fancy synonym for magic.

Comment: [your grandkids called](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyonic_antitelephone) and they say they know the science-based answer.

Comment: Essentially you have asked "these things that don't exist, how do I build a machine using them ?".

Comment: @BalaMurugan welcome.. maybe it helps to get an answer here, when you would change the "science-based" tag in a "science-fiction" tag. Tachyons can't exist according to science, because they *must* travel faster than light. So there is no scienced-based answer to your question here, and now.. I'm not going to downvote, I find the idea of energy-yielding-particles for propulsion interesting, but tagged as science fiction it allows more freedom for a scenario..

Answer (score 4):

**Your crew has no idea**

The thing that sold it to them told them that is how it works.  This thing that told them did not understand it very well either.  It told them not to stand too close to the core when it was running because the tachyons might get on them and make their souls get old.  This thing sometimes used the word "ghosts" for "tachyons".  Your crew is not sure they believe in ghosts or tachyons but they don't stand too close.

This propulsion tech was built by unknown entities, long ago.  Layered generations of jacks and mods from different users are glued and bolted along its outside to facilitate it being hooked up at the rear of the ship to make it go.  The ship does go.

There is other stuff like this on the ship.  The coffee maker is of much more recent make and the crew understands it well.

Comment: Very Red Dwarf, :-)